# ManagedProvisioning flow in AOSP android 12 is not similar to Android 10

Tags: android-source, android-12, airwatch

I am trying to integrate airwatch(admin app - intelligent hub).
I was going through Android 12 ManagedProvisioning codebase and found that the Admin App enrollment is taking place before the user consent.

Could anyone please help me out with the way to achieve the flow similar to Android 10 where user consent flow is taking place before the Admin App?

From Android 12 the flow has been changed.

Please let me know if any further info is required from my end.

Reference activity - https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/ManagedProvisioning/src/com/android/managedprovisioning/preprovisioning/PreProvisioningActivity.java;l=96;bpv=0?q=preprov&sq=&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject:packages%2Fapps%2FManagedProvisioning%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fandroid%2Fmanagedprovisioning%2F